# VSCode hashmap autocomplete is not working

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, jsdoc

I am not sure where I did wrong.. This below is my code.

type.d.ts:

```
type _MaterialTable = {
    weight: number
    price: number
}
type Material = {
    [index: string]: _MaterialTable
}
```

test.js:

```
/** @type {Material} */
WeightTable = {};
/** @type {map<string, _MaterialTable} */
WeightTable2 = {}

const x1 = WeightTable['test'];
const x2 = WeightTable2['test'];
```

[image]

The result was always `any` type. Not `_MaterialTable` type.

How can I type this properly? Thank you

Comment: Does type inference work in other situations? I replicated your code and I can see that VSCode correctly infers `x1: Material`.

Comment: It worked with typescript, but I have just installed intellicode. Would that make some problem?

Comment: ok.. fresh install VSCode. Still not working. Is there something wrong? Or some settings I need to make?